# Is there a way to identify if 3rd Party software loaded on my machine is Large Address Aware LAA

Tags: memory, memory-management, 32bit-64bit

I know how to make my own applications Large Address Aware (LAA)

Is there a way to identify if 3rd party software (Excel, Notepad++, etc.) loaded on my machine is LAA or not?

Can I take a dump from Task Manager and interrogate it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a Large Address Aware EXE has a specific flag set in the PE header. To check this flag you can use the command line tool `dumpbin` which is included in the Windows SDK.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx

`dumpbin /header file.exe` is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed.  Couldn't find any info on it anywhere else.